# Google Search Console - BigQuery delays

Tags: google-bigquery, google-search-console

I'm working with the BigQuery integration in Google Search Console, but I'm finding the data is delayed by 2, 3 sometimes 4 days. Anyone else seeing this issue? This is impacting dashboards.

I'm expecting data within 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor data delay using `ExportLog` tables.

This is for us, and its usually 2-3 days

[image]